# Divs with striped background overlapping

Tags: css

I am setting some `padding` placeholders for an element with four overlaying `<div />`s that have different positioning.

```
.top{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: {{element.paddingTop}};
}
.right{
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: {{element.paddingRight}};
}
.bottom{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: {{element.paddingBottom}};
}
.left{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: {{element.paddingLeft}};
}
```

Now I get the following problem:

[image: overlapping paddings]

As you can see, the `width` and `height` seem to be not an exact amount of `px` and since I am not positioning all elements starting from `top` `left` but also sometimes from `bottom` or `right` I have this ugly overlapping effect.
I can solve it by using `background-attachment: fixed` but that cuts off elements that are outside the viewport - so that doesn't fix my problem.
I know, I could use `top` `left` as the reference point for all 4 `<div />`s and calculate the values, but I don't have the `width` nor the `height` of the element in this moment.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ad51xae7/

Comment: I've fought this fight before, and I'd **strongly** recommend that you simply put a single background on the WHOLE thing, then put a background: white on the "middle" where you don't want the background.

Comment: yeah, @cale_b answer make more sense to me.

Comment: @cale_b I get your point, unfortunately I cannot do that because it's an overlay and I wouldn't be seeing the element's content anymore.

Comment: when we talk about css, always have an alternative

Comment: @Horen You're at least going to need to add your HTML to the question, too. And the outputted CSS, not whatever it is you have there with dynamic values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `background-attachment: fixed` to align the background pattern of your padding elements. Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stefanullinger/ghtkkca8/

You can find a more robust example to test with here: https://jsfiddle.net/stefanullinger/t26r9c74/

**Update:**

Here is another approach using the HTML5 canvas element.
https://jsfiddle.net/stefanullinger/pjzw73am/

Comment: "I can solve it by using background-attachment: fixed but that cuts off elements that are outside the viewport - so that doesn't fix my problem." – This will only happen, if you use CSS Transforms to translate your overlay.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to use HTML5 canvas elements and fill them with a pattern to have fine control of the position. This solution will avoid fixed background positioning.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you start out from this sample

```css
.outline {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 25px;
}
.outline:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #19d76e 8%, transparent 8%, transparent 50%, #19d76e 50%, #19d76e 58%, transparent 58%, transparent);
  background-size: 6px 6px;
}
.outline:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #19d76e;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 1px 2px;
}

.outline div{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outline" data-text="Label something">
  <div>Hey there, how does this work?</div>
</div>
```

2:nd version using border image

The image could of course be embedded as a [`data:\[<mediatype>\]\[;base64\],<data>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) preventing extra requests

```css
.outline{
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 240px;
  border-image-slice: 12 12 12 12;
  border-image-width: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  border-image-repeat: repeat repeat;
  border-image-source: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6015/border-image-5.png");
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute">
  Hey there again, better ?
</div>

<div class="outline">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, doesn't work for me though since I am using an overlay which is positioned absolutely.

Comment: @Horen What does that actually mean, when you say _using an overlay_? ... You can wrap and position my solution too absolute

Comment: The content (in your case "Hey there, how does this work?") is not a child element of the outline but rather an element in an iframe. The outline is completely unattached in the parent window.